# How to access public ip from local network?

Tags: networking, internet

Hi everyone I need some help from the network side our office has Public IP but I can't able to access that public ip from our office's local network, I can able to access my office's public IP from outside of the network. I don't know why this happens.

We need to deploy .net API to our office server so the local network also needs to access that public IP when testing time.

Our Office Router is: TP-link C6

Comment: Accessing the web server public IP from your private network will only work if your router supports [NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning? - NYC Networkers](https://web.archive.org/web/20181017232841/https://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/). Most consumer grade routers don't.

Comment: Our Office Router Has NAT Forwarding. so this will support or?

Comment: We need to deploy .net API to our office server so the local network also needs to access that public IP when testing time.

Comment: Please add the extra information to your question.

Comment: Very often split DNS can solve this kind of problem by mapping a subdomai  to the rfc1918 (internal) IP address on the LAN abd the external IP on the WAN.

Comment: For the future: instead of answering in comments please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1777316/edit) the original question to provide more info. I added the info on .net API now for you. This improves the question as it gets more focused, and the relevant info is immediately available.

Answer (score 1):

#### Our office has Public IP but I can't able to access that public IP from our office's local network

Accessing the web server public IP from your private network will only work if your router supports [NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning? - NYC Networkers](https://web.archive.org/web/20181017232841/https://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/). Most consumer grade routers don't.

However, it appears that the TP-link C6 does support hairpinning but some users are having problems getting it working correctly (firmware issues?)

See [Archer C6 hairpin / loopback - Home Network Community](https://community.tp-link.com/en/home/forum/topic/157747?sortDir=ASC&page=1) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer I will check with the TP-Link community.

Comment: I asked to TP-Link Customer Care side they told need to ask the ISP provider side. Like that